# The connection is already open

Tags: vb.net

I just started making this project as i am new to VB.net.

The update part works where there is already a data in the database but the insert part does not work where it should work when there is no data yet of the said `IdNo` when I press save it says the connection is already open

```
Public Sub AddBusinessInfo()
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblbusinessinfo WHERE IdNo=@IdNo", conn)
            Try
                conn.Open()

                With cmd
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNo", IDD)
                End With
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                With dr
                    .Read()
                    If (dr.HasRows) Then
                        Using cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE tblbusinessinfo SET BusinessType=@BusinessType, BusinessName=@BusinessName, RegDate=@RegDate,
                                    MotherCompany=@MotherCompany, TradeName=@TradeName, IPORegNo=@IPORegNo, Reg=@Reg, Province=@Province, District=@District,
                                    CityMuni=@CityMuni, Brgy=@Brgy, ZipCode=@ZipCode, HBNo=HBNo, RFNo=@RFNo, BldgName=@BldgName, StName=@StName,
                                    TelACode=@TelACode, TelNo=@TelNo, FaxACode=@FaxACode, FaxNo=@FaxNo, Email=@Email,
                                    Mobile=@Mobile, SocialMedia=@SocialMedia WHERE IdNo=@IdNo", conn)
                            With cmd1
                                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessType", rbBTypeVal)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessName", txtBName.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegDate", dtBusinessRegDate.Value)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherCompany", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMotherComp.Text), DBNull.Value, txtMotherComp.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TradeName", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTradeName.Text), DBNull.Value, txtTradeName.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPORegNo", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtIPOReg.Text), DBNull.Value, txtIPOReg.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reg", cmbReg.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Province", cmbProvince.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@District", lblDistrict.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityMuni", cmbCityMuni.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brgy", cmbBrgy.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", lblZipCode.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@HBNo", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHBNo.Text), DBNull.Value, txtHBNo.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFNo", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRFNo.Text), DBNull.Value, txtRFNo.Text))
                                If (txtBuildingName.Text = Nothing) Then
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@BldgName", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBuildingName.Text), DBNull.Value, txtBuildingName.Text))
                                Else
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@BldgName", StrConv(txtBuildingName.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase))
                                End If
                                If (txtStname.Text = Nothing) Then
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StName", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStname.Text), DBNull.Value, txtStname.Text))
                                Else
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StName", StrConv(txtStname.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase))
                                End If
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelACode", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLAC.Text), DBNull.Value, txtLAC.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelNo", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLTN.Text), DBNull.Value, txtLTN.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaxACode", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFAC.Text), DBNull.Value, txtFAC.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaxNo", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFTN.Text), DBNull.Value, txtFTN.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBusinessEmail.Text), DBNull.Value, txtBusinessEmail.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMobile.Text), DBNull.Value, txtMobile.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocialMedia", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSocMedia.Text), DBNull.Value, txtSocMedia.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNo", IDD)
                            End With
                            conn.Close()

                            If (txtBName.Text = "" Or cmbReg.Text = "" Or cmbProvince.Text = "" Or cmbCityMuni.Text = "" Or cmbBrgy.Text = "" Or lblDistrict.Text = "") Then
                                MsgBox("Fields with red texts are required!")
                            Else
                                Dim res As Integer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to update the data?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "System")
                                If (res = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
                                    conn.Open()
                                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                    MsgBox("Success!")

                                End If
                            End If
                        End Using
                        conn.Close()
                    Else
                        Using cmd2 As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblbusinessinfo (IdNo, BusinessType, BusinessName, RegDate, MotherCompany, TradeName, IPORegNo, Reg,
                                                        Province, District, CityMuni, Brgy, ZipCode, HBNo, RFNo, BldgName, StName, TelACode, TelNo, FaxACode,
                                                        FaxNo, Email, Mobile, SocialMedia) VALUES (@IdNo, @BusinessType, @BusinessName, @RegDate, @MotherComp, @TradeName,
                                                        IPORegNo, @Reg, @Province, @District, @CityMuni, @Brgy, @ZipCode, @HBNo, @RFNo, @BldgName, @StName, 
                                                        @TelACode, @TelNo, @FaxACode, @FaxNo, @Email, @Mobile, @SocialMedia)")
                            conn.Open()
                            With cmd2
                                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNo", IDD)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessType", rbBTypeVal)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessName", txtBName.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegDate", dtBusinessRegDate.Value)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherComp", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMotherComp.Text), DBNull.Value, txtMotherComp.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TradeName", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTradeName.Text), DBNull.Value, txtTradeName.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPORegNo", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtIPOReg.Text), DBNull.Value, txtIPOReg.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reg", cmbReg.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Province", cmbProvince.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@District", lblDistrict.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityMuni", cmbCityMuni.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brgy", cmbBrgy.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", lblZipCode.Text)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@HBNo", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHBNo.Text), DBNull.Value, txtHBNo.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFNo", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRFNo.Text), DBNull.Value, txtRFNo.Text))
                                If (txtBuildingName.Text = Nothing) Then
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@BldgName", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBuildingName.Text), DBNull.Value, txtBuildingName.Text))
                                Else
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@BldgName", StrConv(txtBuildingName.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase))
                                End If
                                If (txtStname.Text = Nothing) Then
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StName", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStname.Text), DBNull.Value, txtStname.Text))
                                Else
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StName", StrConv(txtStname.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase))
                                End If
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelACode", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLAC.Text), DBNull.Value, txtLAC.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelNo", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLTN.Text), DBNull.Value, txtLTN.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaxACode", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFAC.Text), DBNull.Value, txtFAC.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaxNo", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFTN.Text), DBNull.Value, txtFTN.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBusinessEmail.Text), DBNull.Value, txtBusinessEmail.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMobile.Text), DBNull.Value, txtMobile.Text))
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocialMedia", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSocMedia.Text), DBNull.Value, txtSocMedia.Text))
                            End With
                            conn.Close()
                            If (txtBName.Text = "" Or cmbReg.Text = "" Or cmbProvince.Text = "" Or cmbCityMuni.Text = "" Or cmbBrgy.Text = "" Or lblDistrict.Text = "") Then
                                MsgBox("Fields with red texts are required!")
                            Else
                                Dim res As Integer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to update the data?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "System")
                                If (res = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
                                    conn.Open()
                                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                    MsgBox("Success!")

                                End If
                            End If
                        End Using
                    End If
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Already solved it. cmd2 has missing parameters and should be like this:

```
    Using cmd2 As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblbusinessinfo (IdNo, BusinessType, BusinessName, RegDate, MotherCompany, TradeName, IPORegNo, Reg,
                                                    Province, District, CityMuni, Brgy, ZipCode, HBNo, RFNo, BldgName, StName, TelACode, TelNo, FaxACode,
                                                    FaxNo, Email, Mobile, SocialMedia) VALUES (@IdNo, @BusinessType, @BusinessName, @RegDate, @MotherComp, @TradeName,
                                                    IPORegNo, @Reg, @Province, @District, @CityMuni, @Brgy, @ZipCode, @HBNo, @RFNo, @BldgName, @StName, 
                                                    @TelACode, @TelNo, @FaxACode, @FaxNo, @Email, @Mobile, @SocialMedia)", conn)'
```

Comment: already solved it. cmd2 had missing parameters

Comment: You don't need a reader at all and don't pull down the entire record if all you need is to know if it exists. Just use `Select Count(*) From tblbusinessinfo WHERE IdNo=@IdNo;` Then `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cmd2 declaration, you forgot to specify the connection variable.

```
Using cmd2 As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblbusinessinfo (...)", ---> conn <---)
```

or specify seperately:

```
cmd2.Connection = conn
```

Comment: Yep. I just noticed it and was editing this post. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling `conn.Open()` twice:

First at the beginning, right after `Try` keyword

Second time, if `If (dr.HasRows) Then` condition fails it goes to `Else` part, where you `conn.Open()` after `Using` statement.

Just remove extra `Open` method and you'll be fine :)

Comment: im sorry  but which one should i remove? kindly point out because im really having a hard time. sorry again

Comment: @lowkeylegendarymike The one after `Using` statement.

Comment: @Michael Turczyn the update works but the insert doesn't. it says connection must be valid and open

Comment: Try disposing `dr` object before insert statement: `dr.Dispose()`

Comment: still the same error after disposing dr